# Aggregate and group dataframe rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, linear-programming

```
# import the module
import pandas as pd
 
# creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' :['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
                  'Size' :[200, 70, 60, 140, 40],
                  "CPU":[25.7, 5.1, 6.2, 15.1, 10]})


df
```

#Need to find rows where the sum of Size <= 100 and sum of CPU <= 100

#Need to find how many groups of rows we can create with above filter criteria

Also can this be looked as an optimization problem i.e linear optimization?

Comment: post a more representative df, the current one does not have **groups** of rows that sum up to `Size < 100`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thanks for your response.  size 60 and 40 equals 100 so that should be part of 1 group. Apologies it should be Size <=100

Comment: Your description looks like a homework assignment and doesn't contain any (parts of) attempts at actually solving the problem. What did you try yourself? What are you stuck on? StackOverflow is here to help you with specific or technical problems, not to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly above problem can easily be formulated as a mixed integer linear program (MILP). Please see the below code listing. I have used Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver. or tools can easily be installed as
`pip install ortools`

```
import pandas as pd
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp
 
# creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' :['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
                  'Size' :[200, 70, 60, 140, 40],
                  "CPU":[25.7, 5.1, 6.2, 15.1, 10]})

# since ortool's CP-SAT solver cannot handle floats natively,
# use a scaling factor to convert floats to integer
scaling_factor = 10
df["CPU"] = [int(i) for i in df["CPU"] * scaling_factor]
df = df.set_index("name")

model = cp.CpModel()
    
# create decision variables
# boolean variable each for a name
dv = {i : model.NewBoolVar("name_" + i) for i in df.index}

# sum of Size <= 100
model.Add(sum(dv[i] * df[df.index == i].Size[0] for i in df.index) <= 100)

# sum of CPU <= 100
# above will translate to : sum of CPU <= 1000, since scaling factor is 10
model.Add(sum(dv[i] * df[df.index == i].CPU[0] for i in df.index) <= 100 * scaling_factor)

# custom callback class that will help us in collecting all 
# feasible solutions as solver finds them
class VarArraySolutionCollector(cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.solution_list = []

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.solution_list.append([self.Value(v) for v in self.__variables])


solver = cp.CpSolver()
solution_collector = VarArraySolutionCollector([dv[i] for i in df.index])
solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_collector)

# collect all solutions
all_solutions = solution_collector.solution_list
```

`all_solutions` is a list of list containing the following :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # no elements are selected
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], # only C3 is selected
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], # C3 and C5 are selected
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], # only C5 is selected
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]] # only C2 is selected
```